# display binary pdf with form data

Tags: perl, pdf, binary

I have a script in Perl that pic up some binary data from a databae and displays it in a new window. This works gracefully with images and regular Pdf files. But when the pdf contains form data(think its called Fdf *) it just wont work. Any ideas? For now im just checking if its an pdf(they are always saved as Pdf) and print it in the script like so. Do i need some special case for pdf´s with form data?

- Looks like this.[Pdf with form](http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/PDFFormandnormalPDF.png)

  ```
  if($extension eq 'pdf'){ 
   print $binaryData;
  }else{
   <img src="data:image/<%$extension%>;base64,<%$binaryData%>" />
  }
  ```

Should add that there is no problem displaying the Pdf´s if they are hosted on the server.

Comment: Have you tried embedding the PDF form using <object> tag? more info here: http://pdfobject.com/markup/

Comment: The object tag works fine with regular Pdf´s...not working for the ones with forms :(

Comment: SOLUTION: This was done in Perl and it turns out autohandler,loghandler and whatnot contained some NEWLINE characters, which made some of the    PDS´s (not all) corrupted. How its gonna be possible to maintain and keep others from putting newlines in those files is hard to say. If anyone know of a solution to wash theese xtra new lines from the request before printing the binary file it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some testing, I found that the problem is with your PDF file, rather than the method you've employed to embed the PDF.

It could be that your PDF file is protected from being embedded?

I tried this quick and it works fine for me:

```
<object data="http://www.thewebjockeys.com/TheWebJockeys/Fillable_PDF_Sample_from_TheWebJockeys_vC5.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

  <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
  No biggie... you can <a href="myfile.pdf">click here to
  download the PDF file.</a></p>

</object>
```

Preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/26C5J.png

Comment: The Fillable_PDF_Sample_from_TheWebJockeys_vC5.pdf works from ur example but as soon as i add a form field(Adobe or foxit) it gets the same error. "File damage and could not be repaired". If i save as pdf via Photoshops it works alright. If i re-save the photoshop created file with adobe, the error is there again! Its obviousely not about the form fields

Comment: This was done in Perl and it turns out autohandler,loghandler and whatnot contained some NEWLINE characters, which made some of the    PDS´s (not all) corrupted. How its gonna be possible to maintain and keep others from putting newlines in those files is hard to say. If anyone know of a solution to wash theese xtra new lines from the request before printing the binary file it would be much appreciated.

Comment: can't you call `trim` function (on each line) to remove any leading/trailing line breaks and other chars?

Comment: Something like that needs to be done but how would i intercept the request? It would be somewhere in $m object but I only manage to modify the current autohandler, not the preceding where the actual linebreaks are added.